# Модели к уже существующим таблицам

Tags: python, django

Если таблицы в базе данных (со связями т.д.) уже созданы, то нужно ли их все равно описывать в моделях?

Comment: Да. И будет нелишним пересоздать их через модели

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Описывать стоит в любом случае. Описание моделей предоставит доступ к orm django, который позволит управлять запросами в БД.

Команда:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

позволит создать модели автоматически, но данные модели будут неуправляемы (`managed=False`), данное поведение указано в [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models) ([на русском](https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/ref/django-admin.html#inspectdb))

Для этих моделей не будут созданы миграции. Если сделать их управляемыми (`managed=True`), то можно создать миграции:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

И, т.к. таблицы уже существуют, указать, что они имеются в БД:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

После, можно вносить изменения в структуру существующих таблиц.

Comment: То что нужно) Спасибо!